# Batch - Match files and folders by filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

Okay so I'm a complete noob at batch programming but I have not found a software tool that can do exactly what I need so I´m thinking a small batch program might be what I need.

I have a folder containing 210 files named: `0_107, 1_107, 2_107 etc. up to 209_107`.

I then have another folder which contain 210 subfolders named: 0, 1,2 etc. up to 209.

I want to move 0_107 into folder `0` and `1_107` into folder `1` and so forth.

I have tried using the software tool `RoboBasket` but this would require med to create 210 rules and I might need to do this multiple times so this is not desirable.

Can anyone help me to create this small batch file ? - keep in mind I have no knowledge of batch programming

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: Not a post for SO. You should go to some freelance site. Here you can find help with some your scratch of bat file.

Comment: You have to try freelance site and I down-voted since its not SO MO.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a PowerShell scripting task. I would learn a little more about folder and file management in PowerShell and write a script to execute what you need.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315304.aspx

Comment: +1. If he really I just starting he should stop using batch files and use powershell or Windows scripting host